# aggregateByKey is not updating the value of the initial set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

The values in `hllTotal` are updated, but `hllToday` remains zero for every key.
Could anyone please help, why `hllToday` is not getting updated here?

```
 val hllToday: HllSerializable = new HllSerializable(new HLL(13, 5))
 val hllTotal: HllSerializable = new HllSerializable(new HLL(13, 5))

 val initialSet = (hllToday, hllTotal)
 val rdd7 = combinedRdd.map(tuple => {
      tuple.segmentId -> (tuple.entryTime, tuple.exitTime, tuple.hll)`
    }).aggregateByKey(initialSet)(
      (acc: (HllSerializable, HllSerializable), v: (Long, Long, HllSerializable)) => {
        if (v._1 == today_ts) {
          acc._1.getHll.union(v._3.getHll)
        }
        acc._2.getHll.union(v._3.getHll)
        acc
      }, (acc1: (HllSerializable, HllSerializable), acc2: (HllSerializable, HllSerializable)) =>    {
        acc1._1.getHll.union(acc2._1.getHll)
        acc1._2.getHll.union(acc2._2.getHll)
        acc1
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently  this code is never called :

```
if (v._1 == today_ts) {
    acc._1.getHll.union(v._3.getHll)
 }
```

Try to replace `if (v._1 == today_ts)` with `if(true)` to see whether `hllToday` gets updated